# Yum, force the update of dependencies

Tags: centos, yum

I have a package with several dependencies. I updated my repo with the given package and his dependencies but when I'm updating the package dependencies are not updated since the required versions are already installed.

How could I force those dependencies to be updated?

Here's an example to clarify it:

I have installed

```
RPM_A_1.0
```

Who have in dependencies :

```
RPM_B version 2.1
RPM_C version 1.1
```

Now I updated my repo so I have the following versions:

```
RPM_A_2.0
RPM_B version 2.1-12
RPM_C version 1.1-12
```

When I call `yum update RPM_A` the others RPMs are not updated and I would like to force those updates

Comment: Why don't you just use `yum update` to update the whole system?

Comment: I can't call yum update, the packages I update are done via a puppet manifest. If I don't find the solution I could add all the RPMs in the manifest file, but if I add new dependencies then I have to add them in the manifest so it's not optimale

Comment: Can you use `yum-builddep RPMA_A` to do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this with your current set up. Puppet only checks to see if RPM_A version 2.0 is installed. If it sees it is installed and at the desired version, its job is pretty much down.

As for when puppet/yum updates the package RPM_A from 1.0 to 2.0, unless there's a specific dependency in RPM_A that says it needs specific newer versions of RPM_B and RPM_C, yum will not go out and fetch the new versions of RPM_B and RPM_C. It will see the packages as already installed and since you're only wanting to update RPM_A, there's no need to get the new versions of RPM_B and RPM_C.

There's a few ways to do what you want:

1. If you're the person who is compiling RPM_A, you can put the specific version requirements for RPM_B and RPM_C in the spec file so yum will go fetch them when RPM_A is updated.
2. You can make package types for RPM_B and RPM_C and put them in your manifest and make RPM_A depend on them.
3. Create some meta package that only exists to list the specific verions of RPM_A, RPM_B, and RPM_C that you need installed. This option is kind of dumb since it is basically the same thing as option 2 but you're doing the same work in a spec file instead of a puppet manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm compiling the RPM, but I don't want to modify my RPM_A to make it require the others packages since the RPM works fine with the oler versions, it is just that for my system I need the other package up to date! So I'll go with option 2!